# How to replace a string of a column with space or ''

Tags: sql-server

I have a columns in tbl in which i have values like

```
X    Y       Z
1    4   123/1232221
2    3   234/3454455
3    2   UNKNOWN 123234
```

Now what i want is when i trigger a query 'UNKNOWN' will replace with space

Like below:

```
X    Y       Z
1    4   123/1232221
2    3   234/3454455
3    2    123234
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks In advance !!!

Comment: what about `replace(z,'UNKNOWN','')` ?

Comment: I put your code waiting for output as it is very large database it will take 2 hours to run it completly

Comment: Thanks @Ganesh_Devlekar your code work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correct the table :

```
update tbl
set z = replace(z,'UNKNOWN','')
where z like '%UNKNOWN%';
```

To query the table with the UNKNOWN [replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql)d

```
select x, y, replace(z,'UNKNOWN','') as z
from tbl;
```

Comment: Uhm, so is that good or bad news?  If you ran that first update statement then yeah, there shouldn't be any "UNKNOWN" in that z field in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Would this suffice?
`UPDATE table SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, 'UNKNOWN', ' ');`

Answer (score 0):

use replace function,
 REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
  in your case string expression in value of your column z. If in some row column 
  doesn't have  value with string 'UNKNOWN', value of that column in row  will 
  remain the same.
  you can find more on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql

```
select x,y,replace(z,'UNKNOWN',' ') as z from you_table
```

or if you want to update

```
update your_table set z=replace(z,'UNKNOWN',' ')
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.